# Correct usage of .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Trying to add content into individual div-containers I stumbled on the command .innerHTML, which I tried to implement accordingly. Strangely I get the following error:

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null *

I'm running the code over my local Apache server if that makes any difference.

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="header">
  <h1>Startseite</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        Navigation
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript.js

```
var navidiv = document.getElementById('left');
navidiv.innerHTML += "FirstElement";
```

Comment: Aye, as with below answers, you must wait for the DOM to load. This is why I always put my scripts at the end of the body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function()
   var navidiv = document.getElementById('left');
   navidiv.innerHTML += "FirstElement"; 
}
```

The element has to be present in the `DOM`, before you can access it in JS

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your DOM elements have loaded before accessing them with javascript.

Since you are using jquery, your javascript can simply be

```
$(function() {
  var $navidiv = $('#left');
  $navidiv.html($navidiv.html() + 'FirstElement');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**html**

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>Startseite</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        Navigation
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
```

**javascript.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var navdiv=$("#left").html();
    $("#left").html(navdiv+"FirstElement");
});
```

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/gSHS6/)